# Reduce vertices from 14 to 10 while keeping circle shape?

Tags: vertices

What I'm hoping has a basic solution I want to reduce the amount of vertices from 14 to 10 but keep the shape.

[image: Current Shape]

Answer (score 0):

On what looks like a simple shape like that, I'd be inclined to start again and set the number of vertices in the bottom-left corner Properties menu when you first add your initial object. Trying to change them later in the modelling process can be a bit of a bodge! If the menu is minimised, click the down-arrow to show the full properties window.

[image]

Comment: I was fearing that. It's meant to connect to other pieces after this step so it looks like I'll be starting the tutorial from the start. =(

Comment: @IrWin This is from a tutorial? What are they doing to reduce the amount of vertices? Or if they had 10 from the start, why didn't you follow along?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I'm following a tutorial, got to this step and realised he had less vert's than I did. I'm not sure how I ended up with more to be totally honest, it's seems to be a really good tutorial so I put it down to user (my) error.
I'm only 4 days into my Blender adventure so it's almost expected at this point.

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial? - Normally cylinders and circles are created with 32 verts by default when you start Blender so I'm guessing that he would have told you to reduce them to 10 when you created it.